# Azure Flask Application getting ERROR

Tags: python, azure

We are trying to deploy a Python flask application on Azure but keep on reciving 500 error with following trace .

```
StdErr: 
2014-09-22 19:24:07.347000: Unhandled exception in wfastcgi.py: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 710, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 567, in read_wsgi_handler
    return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name)
  File "D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 550, in get_wsgi_handler
    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported' % handler_name)
ValueError: "cpmapp.app" could not be imported
2014-09-22 19:24:07.370000: wfastcgi.py 2.1.0 closed
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues understanding why my apps were failing on Azure.

I'm assuming you're using Azure Web Apps?

You must configure your deployment using 2 important files (web.config & deploy.cmd) and adding a requirements.txt file with the list of dependencies.

[I have a blog post breaking it down](http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/starter-site-for-flask-on-azure-web-apps/)

[This post helped me understand what Azure is doing.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/)